# What is the default script generated by SeeTest Automation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, hp-uft, testcomplete, seetest

What is the default script that auto-generated by ***ExperiTest SeeTestAutomation***. Will that script be editable ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no default language in specifically but u can choose from the list of languages provided. The code will be generated in that language for the seetest commands created

Answer (score 0):

SeeTest Supports multiple languages Java,C# etc and multiple supporting framework like NUnit, JUnit, TestNG etc

Choose the one you prefer from the drop down if you want to record and playback.

If you want to write your own code, just import necessary jars/dll's and start writing your code.